# CircleCI has entered an endless loop after I ran bumpversion

Tags: python, circleci, python-poetry, bump2version

I have several repositories in my project and all of them are integrated in to circleCI.
For each I have a CI run on any push and a bump versions run on merge to main.
This has been working well for a while now.

Today I switched from requirements.txt to poetry, the CI runs were ok but when I merged the branch to main it started an endless loop in CircleCI of bumpversion, I started in 0.0.4 and now I'm up to 0.0.265. Help!!!

My old config.yml:

```
version: 2.1

parameters:
  bump_patch:
    type: boolean
    default: false
  bump_minor:
    type: boolean
    default: false

jobs:
  ci_check:
    docker:
      - image: python:3.11.3-slim
    resource_class: small
    environment:
      PYTHONPATH: /root/project
    steps:
      - checkout # checkout source code to working directory
      - run:
          name: Install git & requirements
          command: |
            apt update && apt install -y git
            pip install pre-commit
            pip install pytest==7.4.2
      - run:
          name: Run pre-commit
          command: |
            pre-commit install
            pre-commit run --all-files

  bump_version:
    docker:
      - image: python:3.11.3-slim
    resource_class: small
    parameters:
      bump:
        type: string
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Installs and setup
          command: |
            apt update && apt install -y git
            pip install bump2version==1.0.1
            git remote set-url origin $GIT_URL_TOKEN
            git config user.email setting.engine.main@gmail.com
            git config --global user.name "CircleCI"
            git push --set-upstream origin ${CIRCLE_BRANCH}
      - run:
          name: Bump version
          command: |
            DATE=$(date -u +%Y.%m.%d_%H%M%S)
            bump2version << parameters.bump >> --message "[skip ci] version bump $DATE"
            git push --no-verify
            git push --no-verify --tags

workflows:
  bump_main:
    jobs:
      - bump_version:
          bump: patch
          filters:
            branches:
              only: main

  run_ci:
    jobs:
      - ci_check

  bump_patch:
    when: << pipeline.parameters.bump_patch >>
    jobs:
      - bump_version:
          bump: patch
          filters:
            branches:
              only: main

  bump_minor:
    when: << pipeline.parameters.bump_minor >>
    jobs:
      - bump_version:
          bump: minor
          filters:
            branches:
              only: main
```

New config.yml:

```
version: 2.1

parameters:
  bump_patch:
    type: boolean
    default: false
  bump_minor:
    type: boolean
    default: false

jobs:
  ci_check:
    docker:
      - image: python:3.11.3-slim
    resource_class: small
    environment:
      PYTHONPATH: /root/project
    steps:
      - checkout # checkout source code to working directory
      - run:
          name: Install git & requirements
          command: |
            apt update && apt install -y git
            pip install pre-commit poetry
            poetry install
      - run:
          name: Run pre-commit
          command: |
            pre-commit install
            SKIP=pytest-check pre-commit run --all-files
      - run:
          name: Run tests
          command: |
            poetry run pytest

  bump_version:
    docker:
      - image: python:3.11.3-slim
    resource_class: small
    parameters:
      bump:
        type: string
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Installs and setup
          command: |
            apt update && apt install -y git
            pip install bump2version==1.0.1
            git remote set-url origin $GIT_URL_TOKEN
            git config user.email setting.engine.main@gmail.com
            git config --global user.name "CircleCI"
            git push --set-upstream origin ${CIRCLE_BRANCH}
      - run:
          name: Bump version
          command: |
            DATE=$(date -u +%Y.%m.%d_%H%M%S)
            bump2version << parameters.bump >> --message "[skip ci] version bump $DATE"
            git push --no-verify
            git push --no-verify --tags

workflows:
  bump_main:
    jobs:
      - bump_version:
          bump: patch
          filters:
            branches:
              only: main

  run_ci:
    jobs:
      - ci_check

  bump_patch:
    when: << pipeline.parameters.bump_patch >>
    jobs:
      - bump_version:
          bump: patch
          filters:
            branches:
              only: main

  bump_minor:
    when: << pipeline.parameters.bump_minor >>
    jobs:
      - bump_version:
          bump: minor
          filters:
            branches:
              only: main
```

Edit:
To clarify, I clicked "stop building" in the settings many times, didn't help.